# Secure SOAP Web Service with OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a Java Spring web application with SOAP and REST web services. Whilst I have figured out how to protect the REST endpoints with OAUTH 2, I am struggling to secure the SOAP endpoints as well.

What I would like to do is, send the access token with each SOAP request. Upon receiving the SOAP request, the server would compare the received token with the token in its InMemoryTokenStore.

Using Java code, how can I access the InMemoryTokenStore token so that the endpoint can use it for comparison purposes?